# SCNShadable - varying var and sample from texture

Tags: ios, swift, shader, scenekit

I'm trying to use shaders through `SCNShadable` but I could not find any good doc on how to get things working. Here's what I'd like to accomplish:

```
func setup() {
    // attach a video to a SpriteKit node that renders to my SceneKit node
    // (might not be key to this question)
    let player = videoPlayer
    let item = player.currentItem!
    let track = item.asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo).first
    let size = track.naturalSize
    let node = SKVideoNode(avPlayer: player)
    node.position = CGPoint(x: size.width / 2, y: size.height / 2)
    node.size = size
    let scene = SKScene(size: size)
    scene.addChild(node)
    videoGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = scene

    let customProjection = getCustomProjection()

    // use custom shaders to render
    let vertexShader = "" +
        "attribute mediump vec2 aVertexPosition; \n" + 
        "uniform mediump mat4 customProjection; \n" + 
        "varying mediump vec3 vDirection; \n" + 

        "void main(void) { \n" + 
          "gl_Position = vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0, 1.0); \n" + 
          "mediump vec4 projective_direction = customProjection * gl_Position; \n" + 
          "vDirection = projective_direction.xyz / projective_direction.w; \n" + 
        "} \n" + 

    let fragmentShader = "" +
        "varying mediump vec3 vDirection; \n" +
        "uniform mediump float someUniformParam; \n" +
        "uniform sampler2D uSampler; \n" +

        "mediump vec4 directionToColor(mediump vec3 direction, mediump float someUniformParam) { \n" +
          "... \n" +
        "} \n" +

        "void main(void) { \n" +
          "gl_FragColor = directionToColor(vDirection, someUniformParam); \n" +
        "} \n" +


    videoGeometry.firstMaterial?.shaderModifiers = [
      "fragmentShader": fragmentShader,
      "vertexShader": vertexShader,
    ]
}

func beforeRender() {
    // somehow pass uniforms values to the shaders
    attachUniforms(customProjection, someUniformParam)
}
```

I could not figure out how to:

- split those shaders logic in the `SCNShadable` [protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNShadable_Protocol/#//apple_ref/c/data/SCNShaderModifierEntryPointGeometry). It sounds like `SCNShaderModifierEntryPointGeometry` runs in the vertex shader, and that the 3 other entry points run the the fragment shader. Looks like I'll have to use `SCNShaderModifierEntryPointFragment` for my fragment logic.
- reference to the builtin uniforms, such as the vertex position (that I named `aVertexPosition`) and the texture (`uSampler`)
- make sure my varying variable is passed from the vertex to the fragments shaders
- pass uniforms parameters to the fragment and vertex shaders before the scene is drawn.

Answer (score 2):

With `SCNShadable`, you write shader code snippets that get included in larger shaders files. I've written a medium post about how I went with it: https://medium.com/@guillaumesabran/working-with-scnshadable-783b4bca20d3#.tcv7r11mj

So that means that I have to forget about controlling the entire shader code, and instead getting some understanding of the environment my code snippets are going to run with.

Variables available in those files are poorly documented on Apple's website, but once you've put your hands on the shader code (see vertex and fragment) things get a bit easier.

For instance, the diffuse texture is named `u_diffuseTexture` so in an `SCNShaderModifierEntryPointFragment` I can do:

```
texture2D(u_diffuseTexture, vec2(0.5, 0.5));
```

Passing varying variables from the vertex to the fragment shader works fine.

Concerning uniforms, things are ok as well once you know how:

```
// in some SCNShaderModifierEntryPointFragment code
#pragma arguments
uniform int someUniformVariable;

#pragma body
...
```

and then I can set the value of the uniform with:

```
videoGeometry.firstMaterial?.setValue(1, forKey: "someUniformVariable")
```

Comment: how do you pass varying variables ?

Comment: I think you declare them in the fragment shader (so in SCNShaderModifierEntryPointGeometry) like `varying vec3 somePosition;` and assign them in the vertex shader (so in one of the other entry points) like `somePosition = vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);`

Comment: it was the `#pragma arguments` that i found confusing, turns out it's not needed at all? As long as i have a `#pragma body` the rest of the code ends up in `main()` while i got both a uniform and a varying in the right place without `#pragma arguments` (!?)

Comment: Horrible documentation :(

to set a value for a texture, one needs to construct an `SCNMaterialProperty` (at least for `samplerCube`)